# Solving for N , I know I am missing a step

Tags: calculus

I started with:

1. S     =      ((M/N) - ((M-c)/N))/((M-c)/N)
       *((M-c)/N)                               *((M-c)/N)
2. S((M-c)/N)  =     (M/N) - ((M-c)/N)
             +((M-c)/N)                + ((M-c)/N)
3. S((M-c)/N)+((M-c)/N) = (M/N)

I am thinking I probably forgot to steps to isolate N earlier in the equation. Would love some help!

\edit

For readability:

$$ S = \frac{M}{N} - \frac{\frac{M-c}{N}}{\frac{M-c}{N}} \times \frac{M-c}{N}\times \frac{M-c}{N} $$

$$ ⇔S(\frac{M-c}{N})  = \frac{M}{N} - \frac{M-c}{N} + \frac{M-c}{N} + \frac{M-c}{N} $$

$$⇔ S(\frac{M-c}{N}) + \frac{M-c}{N} = \frac{M}{N}  $$

Comment: Your first line is perhaps not what you intended. It is of the form S=A/B * B * B which according to the order of operations means $S=\frac{A}{B}\cdot B\cdot B$ when perhaps you meant $S=\frac{A}{B\cdot B\cdot B}$

Comment: When you went from line 1 to line 2 the *s turned int +s.  Then from line 2 to line 3  you lost the two last terms on the right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question, but what I did is, I got the first line of your edited question and solved it for $n$:

$$\text{S}=\frac{m}{n}-\frac{\frac{m-c}{n}}{\frac{m-c}{n}}\cdot\frac{m-c}{n}\cdot\frac{m-c}{n}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{S}=\frac{m}{n}-1\cdot\frac{(m-c)^2}{n^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{S}=\frac{m}{n}-\frac{(m-c)^2}{n^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{S}=\frac{mn}{n^2}-\frac{(m-c)^2}{n^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{S}=\frac{mn-(m-c)^2}{n^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{S}n^2=mn-(m-c)^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{S}n^2-mn+(m-c)^2=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Use the quadratic formula:

---

$$n=\frac{-\left(-m\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(-m\right)^2-4\cdot\left(\text{S}\right)\cdot\left((m-c)^2\right)}}{2\cdot\left(\text{S}\right)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$n=\frac{m\pm\sqrt{m^2-4\text{S}(m-c)^2}}{2\text{S}}$$